# Mac Application Issue

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am using `GData.Framewok` in my Mac App for Uploading any photo to Picasa Web Album. But I am getting following errors when i am trying to build the project.
I tried all the ways but still missing something.Please suggest what i am doing wrong.

**Errors**

> "_kGDataPhotoAccessPrivate", referenced from:
>   -[GooglePhotosSampleWindowController createAnAlbum] in GooglePhotosSampleWindowController.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataPhotoTimestamp", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref-to-GDataPhotoTimestamp in
>   GooglePhotosSampleWindowController.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataServiceGooglePhotos", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref-to-GDataServiceGooglePhotos in
>   GooglePhotosSampleWindowController.o
>
> "_kGDataGooglePhotosImageSizeDownloadable", referenced from:
>
> -[GooglePhotosSampleWindowController saveSheetDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:] in
>   GooglePhotosSampleWindowController.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataEntryPhotoAlbum", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref-to-GDataEntryPhotoAlbum in
>   GooglePhotosSampleWindowController.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataEntryPhoto", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref-to-GDataEntryPhoto in
>   GooglePhotosSampleWindowController.o
>
> "_kGDataPhotoAccessPublic", referenced from:
>   -[GooglePhotosSampleWindowController createAnAlbum] in GooglePhotosSampleWindowController.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataUtilities", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref-to-GDataUtilities in
>   GooglePhotosSampleWindowController.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataEntryPhotoComment", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref-to-GDataEntryPhotoComment in
>   GooglePhotosSampleWindowController.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataQueryGooglePhotos", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref-to-GDataQueryGooglePhotos in
>   GooglePhotosSampleWindowController.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataEntryPhotoTag", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref-to-GDataEntryPhotoTag in
>   GooglePhotosSampleWindowController.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataHTTPFetcher", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref-to-GDataHTTPFetcher in
>   GooglePhotosSampleWindowController.o
>
> "_kGDataGooglePhotosDropBoxUploadURL", referenced from:
>   -[GooglePhotosSampleWindowController addToDropBoxClicked:] in GooglePhotosSampleWindowController.o ld: symbol(s) not found collect2:
>   ld returned 1 exit status

All Code of uploading photo is in GooglePhotosSampleWindowController.m file but when i am bulding my project following above errors came.
I am following this link http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary

Thanks in advance !

Comment: We can't help you unless you show us your code.

Comment: Did you add the Framework to your project ?

Comment: Anand you are not assigning any value to NSString *photoName; That's why you are getting error.

Comment: @Paul R - i have added the Gdata.Framework in my project.

Comment: @Brogrammer : When i am using object of GooglePhotosSampleWindowController in another class  i am getting above error

Answer (score 2):

You are not linking that framework with your application.

Assuming you are using Xcode 4.2, check the build phases for the target.  Under "Link Binary with Libraries" the framework should appear

Comment: I am using X-Code 3.2.5 for my application

Comment: Same comments but you need to look in the targets general info panel